# Is it possible to have charts and graphs in WinForms applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, charts

I want to know, is it possible to have charts and graphs in WinForms Applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some sort of library. [This one](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html) is open source. Microsoft has [their own](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c).

Comment: Also http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/chart.aspx & http://www.componentone.com/superproducts/chartwinforms/

Comment: Also .NET 4 now has the MS one built in.

Answer (score 1):

- [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c)